# crash when add and remove sprite in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

i am doing something wrong, maybe someone could help me .

when app is start i add a sprite as a child,from DB like this :

```
b_pic=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:basic_pic];
    b_pic.position=ccp(160,175);
    [self addChild:b_pic];
```

then i do things,and run animation, so before animation starts, i remove the sprite with :

```
[b_pic.parent removeChild:b_pic cleanup:YES];
```

and then i am trying to add it back, BUT its crashes. i add it with :

```
b_pic=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"regular.png"];
    b_pic.position=ccp(160,175);
    [self addChild:b_pic];
```

what am i doing wrong here ?
i cant understand this child and parent thing.

i have also tried to remove the sprite with :

```
[self removeChild:b_pic cleanup:YES];
```

thanks a lot .

Comment: Does it crash on [b_pic.parent removeChild:b_pic cleanup:YES];? try [self removeChild:b_pic cleanup:Yes];

Comment: What does your crash stack look like and or where does it crash exactly?  With cocos2d for me it most often crashes when I remove a sprite too early when something calls on it.

Answer (score 0):

The sprite is an autorelease object in cocos2d. So when you remove the sprite the `CleanUp` should be NO like so...

```
[self removeChild:b_pic cleanup:NO];
```